# Excel Conditional Formatting Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have conditional formatting set up on a column of dates to higlight when the date is coming up to a 5 year renewal mark. However I need to be able to change toe formaula for formatting according to the text value in a different column

For example, my date column has been conditionally formated to turn red if the date is more than 5 years old. I want to link the formatting formula to another column that states client type. So if client is an individual, then turn the date column red when its 5 years old. If the client is a corporation, I need to the date to turn red if the date is 1 year old

Im struggling putting to seperate "IF" functions into the same cell. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using two separate conditional format clauses. Test for individual and 5 yrs in one, set style to late_person. Test for corp and 1 yr in other, set style to late_biz. Create both styles as red for now. Later if you choose to use different shades of red, or even different colors, just change the style definition, and not worry about recreating, and testing, the conditions.

Comment: You can use AND function. AND(Individual,>5years)=TRUE in first formatting condition box  and similar AND(Corp,>1year)=TRUE condition in second formatting box. Also do mention your current formula for reference and necessary modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how your data is organized in your sheet and what formula you are currently using to format the cell. Based on my understanding of your issue, I am putting here an Indicative Solution.  You may have to modify it  based on how you data is organized in your sheet.

This solution uses two Conditional Formatting 'Formula' rules set up on the same cell. It uses YEARFRAC function to measure Year difference between two dates and an AND condition to additionally check Client Type. YEARFRAC function is available in Excel 2007 onwards on Windows.

In this example Column A has Client Type, B has Start Date. Conditional Fomating Rule is applied on Column B as follows. In the screenshot Columns C & D are only informative for reference.

Rule 1 - The formula is

```
=AND(A2="C",YEARFRAC(NOW(),B2,1)>=1)=TRUE
```

NOW() Picks up the current date from your system.

Rule 2 - The formula is

```
=AND(A2="I",YEARFRAC(NOW(),B2,1)>=5)=TRUE
```

Set the same color format for both the rules as desired. Do a Paste Special - Formats for the remaining cells of the column.

[image]